# Angular log in doesn't work iphone 6

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, iphone

i have a problem with log in in my site - it doesn't work on iphone 6.
Here's my code:

JS:

```
$scope.signin = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: link,
            data: $.param({
                action: 'sign_in',
                username: $scope.username,
                password: $scope.password
            }),
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
            .then(function successCallback(response){
                if (response.data === true)
                console.log(response);
                    $location.path('/home');
                } else {
                    console.log('wrong stuff');
                }
            }, function errorCallback(response){
                console.log(response);
                console.log('error');
            });
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <form class="form-signin">
       <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
       <label for="username" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
      <input type="username" ng-model="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
       <input type="password" ng-model="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-click="signin()">Sign in</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

In my website on computer after click "Sign in" i get cookies from server, and angular rout move me to "/home".

When i click "Sign in" on iphone 6 it looks like it is failing when the response returned by the server, and nothing happens. 
Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: I do not see an `if` for your `else`.

Comment: @PrerakSola Yeah, i correct that. In my code there wasn't that mistake. Sign in still doesn't work on iphone.